# simple shell script to add 2 variables

Tags: shell, scripting

Hi I'm trying to get this simple she'll script to work but I keep encountering the error:

bday.sh[9]: 2015-1987: not found

bday.sh[9]: yearb=: not found

Here is my code so far

```
echo "what year is it?"
read "year"
echo "what year were you born?"
read "byear"
"yearb"="$( ( "$year"-"$byear" ) )"
echo "$yearb"
```

Thanks in advance guys!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Kudos for quoting, but it really just applies to parameter expansion, like in `echo "$yearb"`.

Unexpanded variable names (without a preceding `$`) don't need quoting, and sometimes can't have it:

```
yearb=$(( year - byear ))
```

Also, the syntax `$((` (arithmetic expansion) is its own syntactic element so no spaces are allowed.

`$( (..) )` is instead `$(..)` (command expansion) with a nested `(..)` (subshell).

Here's a complete example:

```
$ cat script 
echo "what year is it?"
read "year"
echo "what year were you born?"
read "byear"
yearb=$(( $year - $byear ))
echo "$yearb"

$ bash script
what year is it?
2015
what year were you born?
1970
45
```

Comment: Ok I changed it to look the same as yours but I still get the error 
bday.sh[9]: year: not found ,  I haven't really learnt much about quotation marks so I've just been including them in all my tests and this is the 1st time I've had a problem... Would you be able to explain in a bit more detail or possible provide some reading material, I appreciate your help!

Comment: @JONAS402 I updated it with a complete example incorporating this. See if it's still the same.

Comment: This works perfect, so if I had not included the whitespace between brackets but kept the quotation marks would it still of failed? Thank you so much for your help :)

Answer (score 2):

Addition can also be performed like

echo "$a + $b" | bc